# What is the appropriate place to ask for help with personal bugs on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, flags, bug-reports

As an example, earlier today I was watching a bounty end on a question that I answered, and I was waiting for the bounty to be automatically awarded to me. When the grace period ended, I had not received the bounty. After a couple hours I was considering to ask someone why I didn't get the bounty or if there was some bug in the process. Turns out I just need to wait about 4 hours after the grace period ended for it to automatically award it.

The above problem is no longer an issue, but it got me thinking. If there was a bug that did persist, *Who should I turn to if I experience a personal problem on the site?* What is the most appropriate place? I considered flagging my answer under the category "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)", posting a question on meta Stack Overflow, or posting a question on meta Stack Exchange.

I feel like flagging would be the most applicable; However, I felt like it may have been a mistake on my end, because it was the first time I posted an answer for a bounty.  If it was my mistake, then someone on the meta could have pointed out the issue, instead of wasting a moderator's time, and future people with the same issue could learn from the question.

Comment: This is confusing, what do you mean by a "personal problem"?

Comment: (also, most personnel bugs seem to go unfixed ;) )

Comment: heheh @jonsca! And incidentally, Jonathan: Flagging moderators is actually not the appropriate way; that's not what we do. Posting here is a good idea, though. (though as you note, in this case you figured things out)

Comment: I meant, if something on the site is not functioning correctly for myself, but is not a reproducible bug, and it does not seem to affect others. Andrew: If flagging moderators is incorrect in this situation, then that answers my question!

Comment: @JonathanGawrych Okay, thanks for clarifying. Yes, as Andrew mentioned, you're in the right place for reporting the bug.  Some of the features of the sites work off scripts that only run periodically, and that might be the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty certain this isn't a bug.

Generally, as @jonsca pointed out, many features, such as awarding badges etc, work off scripts that may only run once a day, or on other periods.

If you look at rep in general across SE, you will see it isn't quite real time - system reconciliations, updates, fraud scripts etc all mean that you can't rely on a rep score until after end of day, for example.

So my advice would be to not worry about instant reward - give it some time, and it'll happen :-)